# Proving a subspace under a linear transformation by the closure of standard addition and scalar multiplication

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, transformation

$T(x,y,z)= (3x-2y, -2x+3y, 5z)$ be a linear transformation from $\mathbb{R}^3$ to $\mathbb{R}^3$ 
Show that $A= \{(u,v,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3~|~(u,v,w)=T(x,y,z)\}$ for some $(x,y,z)$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$
is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$ by proving that it is closed under standard addition and scalar multiplication.

Comment: To clarify isn't the subspace should be, $A\{(u,\,v,\,w)\in\mathbb{R}^3\,|\,(u,\,v,\,w)=T(x,\,y,\,z)\}$ ? I mean there's a small typo in what you have written isn't?

Comment: I think you also need to observe that the subspace contains the zero vector. But all this is a bit excessive: the image $R(T)$ of ANY linear operator is a subspace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Remarks

The whole exercise is equivalent to prove that the image $A:=\operatorname{im}(T)$ of a linear operator $T:V\rightarrow W$ is a linear subspace of $W$.

Following the remark by @LinearAlgebra, I will use

$$A=\{(u,v,w)\in\mathbb R^3~|~(u,v,w)=T(x,y,z)\} $$

for some $(x,y,z)\in\mathbb R^3$.

- On addition

Let $(u_1,v_1,w_1), (u_2,v_2,w_2)\in A$, with $(u_1,v_1,w_1)=T(x_1,y_1,z_1)$ and
 $(u_2,v_2,w_2)=T(x_2,y_2,z_2)$. Then

$$(u,v,w):=(u_1,v_1,w_1)+(u_2,v_2,w_2)=T(x_1,y_1,z_1)+T(x_2,y_2,z_2)=\text{linearity of }T=
T(x_1+x_2,y_1+y_2,z_1+z_2)\in A. $$

- On scalar multiplication

Let $(u_1,v_1,w_1)\in A$, with with $(u_1,v_1,w_1)=T(x_1,y_1,z_1)$ and $\lambda\in\mathbb R$. Then

$$\lambda(u_1,v_1,w_1)=\lambda T(x_1,y_1,z_1)=\text{linearity of }T=T(\lambda x_1,\lambda y_1,\lambda z_1)\in A.$$

Comment: Thanks. is there any other view of solving this question besides the properties of subspace

Comment: You are welcome. The above is a general property, independent of the linear map. Feel free to flag it if it is useful.

Comment: how would be find the basis of A?

Comment: check if $T$ is injective and/or surjective etc...before searching for a basis of $A$